# Bootstrap popover not working inside AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a countries list and I am populating those using ng-repeat, everything is working fine. Also, I am trying to show some other details inside each country by using the bootstrap popover and it doesn't seem to work so can someone please help me?

Html Code:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="my_controller">    
<div class="span3 projectCard" ng-repeat="country in all_countries">
    <div class="projectCardHeight">
        <button class="btn close cardClose" ng-click="deleteCountry(country.id)">×</button>
        <div class="cardHeader">Country</div>
        <div class="cardBody">{{country.id}}</div>
        <div class="cardBody">{{country.title}}</div>
        <div class="cardBody"><a href="#" id="pop{{country.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-content="This is the <b>body</b> of Popover" data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('my_controller', function($scope) {  
    $scope.all_countries = [
        {"id":28,"title":"Sweden"},
        {"id":56,"title":"USA"},
        {"id":89,"title":"England"}];
});

function deleteCountry(id)
{
    alert("Do something");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel=popover]")
        .popover({ placement: 'bottom', html: 'true' })
        .click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Please refer to this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shansubra/4bqgX/54/)

Comment: refer to bootstrap docs and use `selector` the same as using jQuery `.on()` in order to delegate event handler, or wrap code in a directive

Comment: do you have any example for the same?

Comment: look at jQuery `on()` docs, or one of the many thousands of posts here regarding event delegation

Comment: Ok. Will check the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5ww8e/1/

Create a new directive called `bs-popover` and apply it together with `ng-repeat`. Trigger `popover` method inside `bs-popover` directive.

Also your js file loading order is wrong, you should load jquery before bootstrap.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work in my page so inside the ng-repeat I used ng-click instead of directive and it works now.

Comment: popover does not close automatically when I click another popover(pop button). Need to open only popover at a time.

Comment: This works for me

app.directive('bsPopover', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("a[rel=popover]").popover({ placement: 'bottom', html:true});
    };
});